# Use input properties to control Angular2 component template tag

Tags: angular, angular2-components

I'd like to be able to control the root element of a @Component instance using an input parameter. I've tried using interpolation to no avail:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  template: `
    <{{tag}}>I wish this would work!</{{tag}}>
  `
})

export class MyComponent {
  @Input() tag: string;
}
```

Unfortunately, the above code throws an error. Does anyone have any ideas on how I can get this to work? I'm largely unfamiliar with Angular2 so if there is a better way to approach this problem I'm open to it.

Comment: The `selector` is the root tag. Why do you want to swap out the element?

Comment: A simple example is a Heading component. I'd like to have a single Heading component that applies consistent class naming (and other behavior I may need to enable in the future). However, there are 6 heading elements - `h1-h6`. I'd like to be able to pass the tag as a parameter. This is a simple use-case but it illustrates my desired behavior and component organization.

Comment: Why not have an `ngSwitch`, then? It would mean a bit of duplication, but would compile at least.

Comment: I was trying to avoid the duplication as some of the components that require configurable markup are more robust, but there may not be a better option. I think [this](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#expanding-ngswitch-) will unblock me. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Maybe using a @Directive would be better in your example with h1-h6: You could simply add it to standard h1-h6 tags and alter them as you wish. E.g. <h1 [mySpecialHeader]="someValueIfNeeded">Header</h1>

Comment: I ended up solving this with a combination of `ngSwitch` and `<ng-container>`: ```<ng-container [ngSwitch]="tag">
           <h1 *ngSwitchCase="h1">{{ text }}</h1>
           <h2 *ngSwitchCase="h2">{{ text }}</h2>
       </ng-container>```